# Anything like Scratch or Google AppInventor but for JavaScript or HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-programming

I'm looking for a programming environment similar to [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) or [AppInventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/) but generating code for JavaScript or HTML5. The basic idea is to build the program using "construction blocks". I need this for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of [Waterbear](http://waterbearlang.com/), so I appreciate the plug, with the caveat that it is still very early and rough, so caveat acceptor. Another HTML block language, also based on [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu) is [DesignBlocks](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/evhan55/designblocks-visual-programming-for-artists), although I'm not sure what the development status is for that.

Answer (score 1):

- [Lilyapp](http://www.lilyapp.org/)  is the only browser based 
  visual programming environment I know of... 
  It uses the flowbased paradigm of Pure-Data & friends 
  rather than the blockbased approach of 
  Scratch & co. Actually it's a visual programming 
  environment running in the browser rather than 
  a tool to create websites. But you might still want to check it out.
- [Yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) is another great example
  of visual programming (for Mashups) and it 
  might fit your needs for educational use.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Waterbear](http://waterbearlang.com/) with [source](https://github.com/dethe/waterbear)

Answer (score 0):

inspect phpBlocks

It is a JavaScript + PHP Backend Solution like AppInventor from Google.

http://www.freegroup.de/software/phpBlocks/demo.html

Greetings

Andreas